# Performance implication for persistent shopping

Tags: magento-1.7, cart, database, performance, persistent

I'm contemplating enabling Persistent Shopping to reduce cart abandonment, though am slightly concerned about the performance implication thereof.

How much more taxing is this going to be on the database, if at all? Looking at the `Mage_Persistent` module, I can already see quite a few things:

1. There is an installer script for the `persistent/session` table which has 6 columns, 3 indexes and 2 foreign keys. This script also adds the `is_persistent` column to the `sales/quote` table.
2. The introduction of two models, `<persistent>` and `<persistent_resource>`
3. A large number of event-observers, listed below:

   - `customer_login`
   - `customer_logout`,
   - `controller_front_send_response_after`,
   - `controller_action_layout_load_before`,
   - `controller_action_predispatch_customer_account_loginPost`,
   - `controller_action_predispatch_customer_account_createpost`,
   - `controller_action_layout_generate_blocks_after`,
   - `controller_action_predispatch`,
   - `checkout_allow_guest`,
   - `customer_customer_authenticated`,
   - `controller_action_predispatch_persistent_index_unsetCookie`,
   - `sales_quote_save_before`,
   - `custom_quote_process`,
   - `controller_action_postdispatch_checkout_onepage_saveBilling`,
   - `customer_register_success`,
   - `controller_action_predispatch_paypal_express_start`,
   - `controller_action_predispatch_paypaluk_express_start`,
   - `controller_action_predispatch_googlecheckout_redirect_checkout`,
   - `controller_action_predispatch_checkout_multishipping_index`,
   - `render_block`,
   - `update_customer_cookies`

Has anybody noticed a performance impact as a result of enabling persistent shopping?

Answer (score 1):

I took a look at the [documentation](http://merch.docs.magento.com/ce/user_guide/Magento_Community_Edition_User_Guide.html#order-processing/shopping-cart-persistent.html%3FTocPath%3DSales%2520%2526%2520Orders%7CAssisted%2520Shopping%7CPersistent%2520Shopping%2520Cart%7C_____0) from Magento.

Looks like the data is shared between session and persistent session.

I think it is almost the same impact as saving sessions in the database.

Maybe some other users can complete or fill in.

Answer (score 1):

> Has anybody noticed a performance impact as a result of enabling persistent shopping?

More storage space used in the session backend (ie. for most our customers, more RAM used on their Redis node in MageStack).

Beyond that, I haven't seen any ill effects.